# Indexing a typescript object that contains various classes from a hierarchy

Tags: typescript

I have an object `someMap : { [ key : string ] : A }`, which contains objects of classes `A` and `B`, with `B` extending `A`.

If I have some strings which map to `A`s and some which map to `B`s, is there some way I could type those string and modify `someMap` so that it is aware what the result of indexing will be? Or am I stuck with `someMap[stringWhichMapsToB] as B`?

Answer (score 0):

> Or am I stuck with someMap[stringWhichMapsToB] as B?

No. Here is the answer:

```
interface A {a:number}
interface B extends A {b:number}

declare var someMap : { 
    stringWhichMapsToB: B,
    [ key : string ] : A 
};

const x /*inferred B*/ = someMap['stringWhichMapsToB'];
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the strings at compile time.

Comment: Then you will have to do the assertion at runtime 